# In Ruby can I have a method that can be used in any class within a specific module

Tags: ruby

I have a logger method that I would like to make accessible to all classes within a module. Is there a way of doing that without just putting the method in a module and including it in every single class? I'd also prefer not to have to call the method with the module (e.g. Module.logger)

From what I can tell, the class does not inherit at all from the module it is in, so I can't figure out anyway of doing this, but I thought I'd ask to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby doesn't have nested classes. The classes aren't in the module. There is no relationship whatsoever between the classes and the module.

The *constants* which reference the classes are namespaced inside the module, but that has nothing to do with the relationship between the classes and the module.

So, no, what you want is not possible, for the simple reason that there is no relationship between the classes and the module that could be exploited to somehow make the method available. You will have to go for good old (mixin) inheritance.

Comment: Cool, yeah that's what I had in my head, just wanted to check and make sure I wasn't missing anything :)

Comment: That's an interesting way of phrasing this, upon reflection it's absolutely true that the *classes* are not related to the modules that contain their constants in any way. Thanks for that. I will say there *is* a relationship that can be discovered through `self.class.name`, but not one that is useful in the way OP is interested in.

Comment: This is _literally_ wrong. Classes are modules, and the nesting of modules is central to how constants are looked up at runtime. However, methods are not constants and are looked up using inheritance, which has nothing to do with module nesting.